# Confusing Kiwi citizens

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Gah! We have:

[new-zealand-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-zealand-citizens) and [nz-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nz-citizens).  Suggest the former as a master synonym tag, given people may have missed the NZ one, we don't just want to re-tag.

Comment: "Confusing Kiwi citizens" They are, aren't they?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm we try :)

Comment: It's not that hard - most of them aren't that bright.  Ohh.. wait.. did I say that out loud?  :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems we do not have [nz-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nz-citizens) in use at present. Seems no need for a synonym but perhaps time to tag OP [status-completed].